# Quicksort without partition function and complexity for worst and best case

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Here is my code for quick sort without the partition function and was trying to figure out the complexity for worst and best case. Can anyone of you help me out with an explanation of how it would work loop by loop or step by step?

```
public static void quickSort(int a[], int first, int last)
{
    int start=first,end=last;
    int mid= (first+last)/2;
    int temp;
    while(start<=end)
    {
        while(a[start]<a[mid])
        {
            start=start+1;
        }
        while(a[end]>a[mid])
        {
            end=end-1;
        }
        if(start<=end)
        {
            temp=a[start];
            a[start]=a[end];
            a[end]=temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
    if(first<end)
    {
        quickSort(a,first,end);
    }
    if(start<last)
    {
        quickSort(a,start,last);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same as with the partition function. You're still partitioning, just that you're doing all the work in a single function rather than having a dedicate partition function.

Comment: hmm. can you explain how to go about. i can see O(n/2) for both the quicksort functions and can not figure out the rest statements.

Comment: anyone? the time comes out to be t(n/2) for both quickSort functions, how to calculate and approximate the rest?

Comment: is my implementation correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct. The outer while loop iterates the whole array once so it has linear time complexity. Both the two inner loops run through each element of the array exactly once for the entire iteration of outer while loop so the overall time complexity of the outer while loop is O(n).

Your calls to quick sort function are same as in the standard function, you have just put them along with partition in the same function.

So overall time complexity of your code is same as standard quick sort algorithm.(O(nlogn) for average case and O(n2) for worst case).

**Dry run for a sample array**

Consider the array 1,7,8,9,6,4,5,2,3,10
Now first=start=0,last=end=9,mid = 4

Iteration1:
since start<=end we enter inside first while loop
now we increment start by until it is less than middle element.
since a[mid] = 6 so we can increment start just by 1 because next element is 7 which is greater than 6 and exit out of first inner loop.
now we repeat the same process with second inner loop
we decrease end just by 1 because 3 is less than 6 and exit out of second inner loop.
now we exchange 7 and 3 and increase start and decrease end.

new array: 1,3,8,9,6,4,5,2,7,10

Iteration2:
start pointing to 8 and end pointing to 2
since start is greater than middle element and end is less than middle element so we do not enter the inner loops and exchange start and end.
increase start and decrease end.

new array: 1,3,2,9,6,4,5,8,7,10

Iteration3:
start pointing to 9 and end pointing to 5
since start is greater than middle element and end is less than middle element so we do not enter the inner loops and exchange start and end.
increase start and decrease end.

new array: 1,3,2,5,6,4,9,8,7,10

Iteration4:
start pointing to 6 and end pointing to 4
since start is greater than middle element and end is less than middle element so we do not enter the inner loops and exchange start and end.
increase start and decrease end.

new array: 1,3,2,5,4,6,9,8,7,10

Iteration5:
start pointing to 6 and end pointing to 4
since start is greater than end so we exit here.

Now you can see that we iterated through the outer loop 5 times but for inner loops we just iterated total 1 time each which is less than n(=10).

Now dry run this array on your own to understand it better.
1,2,3,4,6,5,7,8,9,10.

Comment: but i don't still get how to calculate the inner part complexity. my concept have been always like this: outer loop (n times) inner while loops (n/2) times each. hence n/2+n/2=n and then on multiplication N^2. i know i am wrong here, so need this correction to my understanding

Comment: did i miss your comments?

Comment: i took any array 5,4,3,2,1 and it seems to be failing when both start and end are at 3 that is mid position

Comment: with your answer you never entered any while loop and always went to each if loop for 1 time of outer loop execution. that makes it 5 times, now how to proceed after this. i know i am very poor, but trying to learn

Comment: I went in both inner loops in the first iteration just once.
You can run this code on paper by yourself and check, its fairly easy.

Comment: yes wrote it and understood your first point. you did enter once in the loop. so we iterated for 5 times through the outer loop and 1 each for  inner loop. cool got this. but how does this go about in explaning my time complexity of o(n). after this i will move to quicksort fucntion and call the other halfs and start while loop again. so how will i reach to calculating complexity

Comment: In last line of my answer I asked you to dry run this array on your own to understand it better. 1,2,3,4,6,5,7,8,9,10. Just try it once and see how many iterations inner loops go into.

Comment: never they don't go even once since mid is always greater than start and end is always larger than mid, so what to i get from it?

Comment: can you explain the cost and no of times for each statement line by line, that would be the best help for me , thanks!

Comment: can you please help put